# Properly declaring a function using class members?

Tags: c++, class, declaration

I'm in the process of trying to convert a C program using `struct`s into C++ with `class`es. I am trying to call a member function of a `class B` from within `class A`. Here is a snippet to explain my error:

```
    class Time{
        public:
        Time();
        Time(int hour, int minute);
        int time_Equal(Time &a, Time &b) const;
        -----
        private:
        int hour;
        int minute;
    };

    Boolean Time::time_Equal(Time &a, Time &b) const
    {
        /* If hour of Time "a" equals hour of Time "b" */
        if(a.hour == b.hour){
            if(a.minute == b.minute)
                    return TRUE;
        }
    }

    class DaTime{
        public:
        DaTime();
        DaTime(Day day, Time start, Time end);
        Boolean dt_Equal(DaTime &a, DaTime &b) const;

        private:
        int duration;
        Time start;
        Time end;
    };

    Boolean DaTime::dt_Equal(DaTime &a, DaTime &b) const
    {
            if(time_Equal(a.start, b.start)){
                   if(time_Equal(b.end, a.end))
                          return TRUE;
            }

            else
                    return FALSE;        
    }
```

The error I am getting is that `time_Equal` is not declared in this scope. The reason I do not understand this is because I have included a header file where `Time` is declared before `DaTime`. I don't see the issue with how I have declared the functions.

Comment: `time_Equal` is a member of `Time`, nor `DaTime`. Also, what is `Boolean`? Is it the same as `int`? Your definitions have to match your declarations.

Comment: Boolean is previously defined. It's defined as `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`.

Comment: So `Boolean` is an enum ? Get rid of it, it offers literally zero benefit. Either use `int` or use `bool`. Pick one and stick with it. (preferably the latter).

Comment: If I change the `if(time_Equal(a.start, b.start))` portion to `if(start.time_Equal(a.start, b.start))` the compiler stops complaining. Why is that? That can't surely be a correct way of declaring the member to perform the function on.

Comment: @AllenS Because you made it a member of `Time`, so it has to be called on a `Time` object. In `start.time_equal(a.start, b.start)`, `start` is the object that `this` points at inside the function. In your implementation, however, you are not making use of the `*this` object, so the `start.` prefix seems unnecessary. That's just because you've implemented it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the boolean type is just `bool`.

Second, the return type of the `time_Equal` declaration is `int`, whereas the definition has `Boolean`. Pretty sure you want both to be `bool`. They should at least match.

Third, your `time_Equal` function does not modify its arguments, so you should make them `const` references (`const Time &a` and `const Time &b`).

Fourth, your `time_Equal` function is a non-static member of `Time`, but it doesn't use any of its members. That is, its output depends only on its arguments, and not on the object that `this` points at. This is a code smell. It means your function should probably be a static function or you should change the function to use `this`. So you have two options:

1. Keep it a member and change it to:

   ```
   bool time_Equal(const Time &other) const;
   ```

   And then in the implementation you should compare `*this` with the `other` argument. In this case, you would call it like `a.start.time_Equal(b.start)`.
2. Make it either a `static` member or take it out of the class and make it a friend function and keep it with two arguments:

   ```
   bool time_Equal(const Time &a, const Time &b) const;
   ```

   In this case, you would call it like `time_Equal(a.start, b.start)`.

Fifth, C++ has a built in operator to perform test for equality (`==`) which you can overload for a class. So you can in fact implement the above two options respectively like so:

```
bool operator==(const Time &other) const; // As a non-static member
// or
bool operator==(const Time &a, const Time &b) const; // As a static member or friend function
```

Then you can compare times like so: `a.start == b.start`. Nice, huh?

For more information, see the [operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/150634).

Sixth, your `time_Equal` implementation does not return `false` when it should. You can easily rewrite the body as:

```
return a.hour == b.hour && a.minute == b.minute;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such an elaborate explanation including alternative options.

Comment: @AllenS I should probably mention that the friend function `operator==` overload is usually preferred.

Comment: We just now started learning about operator overloads in class, so I was a bit iffy on trying it. I will try to implement it that way once I get this all resolved. Which, thanks to you and everyone else's help I think I will be able.

Answer (score 1):

Function time_Equal is declared as a non-static member function of a class. So it can be used only with an instance of the class.
Moreover it is declared as having parameters of type `Time`. However in function dt_Equal you call it passing arguments of type `int`

```
        if(time_Equal(a.start, b.start)){
               if(time_Equal(b.end, a.end))
                      return TRUE;
        }
```

You should declare function time_Equal either as a non-member function with two parameters or as member function with one parameter.

As a member function it could look as

```
bool Time::time_Equal( const Time &rhs ) const
{
    return (  hour == rhs.hour  && minute == rhs.minute );
}
```

As a non-member function it must be declared as a friend function of the class because data members hour and minute are defined as private Or if you have getters to hour and minute then there is no necessary to make it friend. In any case it could look as

```
bool Time::time_Equal( const Time &lhs, const Time &rhs )
{
    return (  lhs.hour == rhs.hour  && lhs.minute == rhs.minute );
    // or return (  lhs.get_hour() == rhs.get_hour()  && lhs.get_minute() == rhs.get_minute() );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`time_Equal` is a method in the `Time` class, yet you call it like it is a global function.
An instance level method shall be called on an object.